# Ubuntu 18.04 froze, then fsckd file system scan stuck during reboot (Ctrl+C doesn’t cancel). Maybe due to log in loop days after VNC or x2go install

Tags: boot, 18.04, login, filesystem, vnc

Our system (Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell Precision 7920 tower) froze when I tried to restart Spyder and when I restarted, it would not advance past the fsckd filesystem check (please see images). Since some of the errors seemed network related, I unplugged the ethernet and tried rebooting (same thing happened, but maybe some different errors; see 1st stuck point image). I rebooted and pressed F12 to do a system scan. Everything was good there, so the issue does not seem to be with the hardware. I changed the BIOS settings to default and after rebooting got to the same screen (but with different errors; 2nd image of stuck point). Dell suggested this: booting and pressing F2 -> System config -> STAT Operation -> change from Raid On to AHCI. A warning pops up that this may prevent your OS from booting or require a reinstall. I did not try this yet because I am worried it will wipe the data. Please let me know if this is safe to try. The SSDs are not currently in a RAID configuration.

I think we started having issues sometime after we tried to set up a TigerVNC server and ended up using x2go. Before this crash we could not to log in to one user account, which could be a log in loop error. It seemed like problems were related to X server or not connecting to a monitor or server for that user. We could run the terminal under that user account (e.g., with su boris), but could not launch GUIs from the terminal. If you read the errors in the fsckd scan, there are multiple sessions with that user are starting during fsckd scan, so I wonder if this could be the source of our problem. For a while, we tried using another user account until TeamViewer stopped on that account, but not others (since we are trying to work from home).

The day before the crash I added some paths to PATH and PYTHONPATH in .bashrc and .profile to help Spyder import a python module. I am not sure if this could be part of the problem.

This issue might be similar to the one in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140269/ubuntu-18-04-fsckd-is-not-completing-the-filesystem-check-process-and-also-not-a) with more discussion [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94048/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-ubuntu-18-04-fsckd-is-not-completing-the-filesy)., but there are some differences in the  filesystem check and it seemed like they ended up reinstalling Ubuntu. We have a lot of software that was difficult for us to install/setup and would like to be able to fix this without reinstalling Ubuntu. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Example of filesystem check error when booting up: 
. . . 
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Name Resolution. 
See 'systemctl status systemd-resolved.service' for details
[ OK ] Started Session 3 of user boris. 
[ OK ] Stopped Network Name Resolution
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Name Resolution. 
See 'systemctl status systemd-resolved.service' for details
[ OK ] Started Session 4 of user boris. 
[ OK ] Started xrdp session manager
       Starting xrdp daemon...
[ OK] Started GNOME Display Manager.
Fsckd-cancel-msg:Press Ctrl+C to cancel all filesystem checks in progress

Images: 
[Fsckd-cancel-msg:Press Ctrl+C to cancel all filesystem checks in progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxzgM.png)
[1st stuck point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQe5c.jpg) 
[Stuck point after BIOS default then reboot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMdT9.jpg)
[Warning about switching Raid On to AHCI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5Yzk.png)

Comment: The var/log/cups/error_log file was ~1TB and iteratively repeated this: notifier for subscription 543 (dbus://) went away, retrying! File \"/usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus\" has insecure permissions (0100777/uid=0/gid=0) similar to this issue (https://askubuntu.com/questions/648807/cupsd-using-100-cpu-creating-large-80gb-error-log) and is probably the result of this user error (https://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidently-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc) with ~"sudo chmod a+rwx /" to give new users read/write permissions to work around the log in loop of the main user.